# java:how to display data in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have created one form for holiday, in which user entering date and description of the holiday. So I want to display this data in JTable at runtime. I have getting values of date and description perfectly.

```
String start= single_date.getDate().toString();
String desc_text=description_text.getText();
```

Now help me to display in JTable. I am using netbeans, so I am having JTable in my JForm.

Comment: See [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `Default constructor of JTable` to do it..then try this..

It takes **2-Dimension Object array, and 1-Dimension String array**

```
Object[][] arr = {{"start_val1","desc_text_val1"}, {"start_val2","desc_text_val2"}};


String[] header = {"start","desc_text"}; 

JTable table = new JTable(arr,header);
```

**See this link for a working example:**

http://java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTableclassusingdefaulttablemodelsandaconvenience.htm

Answer (score 0):

JTable is not a complex topic that you need to ask here. I think you should see [this link](http://waltermilner.com/downloads/JavaSwing/UsingJTables.pdf) and also [this one](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0601/hendry/index.html)